# loop with given number of times

Tags: javascript

Iam stucked in one of the higher order function exercises where Iam supposed to loop with the given number of times and everytime it should give half of the passed argument(200) in this case. I made function to make the given number half but when I passed to main function, Iam not getting the result which in this case is 6.25. As Iam still learning js and trying exercises. Here is my code so far.

`

```
function loop ( loops, number , func){
   for(var i=0; i< loops; i++){
      var x= func(number);
     }
     return x;
 }

function halve(x){
  return x/2;
}

console.log(halve(50));
console.log(loop(5 , 200, halve));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is wrong is

```
var x= func(number);
```

inside the loop, because you are creating every time a variable x, and never changing `number`, instead you probably want this:

```js
function loop ( loops, number , func){
   for(var i=0; i< loops; i++){
       number = func(number);
   }
   return number;
 }

function halve(x){
  return x/2;
}

console.log(halve(50));
console.log(loop(5 , 200, halve));
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is initially stored in `x` and `x` is passed each time and the result is stored in `x`

```
function loop ( loops, number , func){
   var x = number;
   for(var i=0; i< loops; i++){
      var x= halve(x);
     }
     return x;
 }

function halve(x){
  return x/2;
}

console.log(halve(50));
console.log(loop(5 , 200, halve));
```